# Python Dictionary value gets assigned into different key

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to code a word-count program in python. For this, I am using dictionary to store count of the words.

Dictionary is of the format d[int] = [array of words].

Upon adding a word, if word is already present in dict,it removes the word and appends to next key.

Upon executing d[index].append(word), it somehow gets added as a new key. Am I doing something wrong? I am using python 3.4.3 and 2.7.9 on Ubuntu.

```
def count_words(s, n):
    d = {}
    d[1] = []
    word_array = []
    for word in s.split():
        if word not in word_array:
            d[1].append(word)
            word_array.append(word)
        else:
            keys = list(d.keys())
            for key in keys:
                if word in d[key]:
                    index = key+1
                    d[key].remove(word)
                    if index in d.keys():
                        print ('appending %s at %d on %s' % (word, index, d[index]))
                        d[index].append(word)
                        #print d[index]
                    else:
                        d[index] = list([word])
            print ('%s -> %s' % (word, d))
    print (d)

def test_run():
    """Test count_words() with some inputs."""
    count_words("cat bat mat cat bat cat", 3)
    #print count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter", 3)
    #print count_words('london bridge is falling down falling down falling down london bridge is falling down my fair lady', 5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_run()
```

Comment: Btw, 4 space indentations would make the code more readable; `index in d.keys()` -> `index in d`, `list([word])` -> `[word]`

Comment: You might take a look at [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)s.

Comment: There are far better ways to solve this. However, it was just a throwaway code I created to check for something. My question is that is it a bug or programming issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you do not break loop

```
for key in keys:
    if word in d[key]:
        code that removes word from d[key] and inserts it into d[key+1] list
```

On certain point of execution dictionary `d` has following content

```
{1: ['bat', 'mat'], 2: ['cat']}
```

Next word in the sentence is `bat` so your code does this:

1. on the first iteration of the loop it finds `bat` in `d[1]`, removes it from there and appends the word into `d[2]` list (at this point dictionary has proper content);
2. on the second iterations it finds `bat` in `d[2]` and proceeds with its removal and creation of a new list in `d[3]`.

You need to break the loop once you have appended `word` into `d[index]`

See http://ideone.com/sROy6m

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to realize what kind of datastructure you're using. It would be more efficient to reverse the order, and use the `collections.Counter` to count the words; should you need the reverse structure (aka words by count), you can build it later:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def words_by_count(s):
    word_counts = Counter(s.split())
    by_count = defaultdict(list)
    for word, count in word_counts.items():
        by_count[count].append(word)

    return by_count

print(words_by_count('cat bat mat cat bat cat'))
```

prints:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['mat'], 2: ['bat'], 3: ['cat']})
```

Comment: I agree, it was just a throwaway code I created to check for something. However, my question is that is it a bug or programming issue?